# Override indexOf() for call from null

Tags: javascript, null, overriding, indexof

I know that it is possible to override Functions in JS like this:

```
var indexOf = String.prototype.indexOf;
String.prototype.indexOf = function(){
    //MY CODE HERE
    return indexOf.call(this, arguments);
};
```

This is overriding `indexOf()` called from a String.
Is it possible to Override `indexOf()` which will be called from null?
`var a = null; a.indexOf("foo")` should return `-1`. Evil right?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible.

Comment: `null` in JS is a primitive value. It is not an object and has no methods.

Comment: Further all very good comments, wrap the function with your function and return `-1` if the object is null.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = null,
b = 'foobar';
console.log( (a+'').indexOf('foo') );
console.log( (b+'').indexOf('foo') );
```

Concatenate null to string then check, if You really want of indexOf

Comment: Thanks,, but this does not work for me, because I can not edit the Vars before calling indexOf().

Comment: Interesting idea :) @bor32 Why do you need to edit the vars? Can you edit the line which call the `indexOf` method?

Comment: @bor32 add `''` before checking `.indexOf`.

Comment: Ok I will explain it a bit more ..I have json file with a condition like "cond":"getValue('bar').indexOf('foo')" and getValue returns a string or null. This String will be executed as a function ... var func = new Function(..)

Answer (score 1):

`null` (and `undefined`) don't support property access (the dot operator), in other words, `null.whatever` never works. So what you're looking for is not possible. [Reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-requireobjectcoercible).

Moreover, some (most?) built-in methods, including `indexOf` also don't support `null` bindings, so `''.indexOf.call(null,...)` won't work either.

I understand the rationale behind your question, having methods on nulls can be useful in "map-invoke" contexts, like

```
 source.map(x => x.someMethod())
```

where you want to return some default value for nulls/undefineds that might occur in the source. Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to do this concisely, you'll have to provide a safety wrapper for possible nulls:

```
 source.map(x => invoke(x, func))
```

where `invoke` is something like `return x === null ? null : func.apply(x)`

Complete example:

```js
let isNull = x => x === null || typeof x === 'undefined';

let invoke = (func, ...args) => x => isNull(x)  ? null : func.apply(x, args);

a = ['foo', 'bar', null, 'bbaazz'];

// z = a.map(x => x.indexOf('a')) // this will fail

z = a.map(invoke(''.indexOf, 'a')); // this works

console.log(z);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Good suggestions. I will see :-)